# Serialize multiple select boxes for Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'll use a toy example to illustrate my problem:

I have a form which gets some details about a user:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
    <input type="text" name="sname" />
    <input type="text" name="birthdate" />
    <select name="hobbies">
        <option>Programming</option>
        <option>Eating cats</option>
        <option>Explaining string theory to my grandmother</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and I'm going to send it to my server with an ajax call so I can give some kind of response without a page refresh:

```
$.post("myserverscript.php", $('#myform').serialize(), function(){...callback...});
```

This works fine.

Now, I need to take the same information about multiple users on the same page. No problem, I just add `[]` to my input names:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="fname[]" />
    <input type="text" name="sname[]" />
    <input type="text" name="birthdate[]" />
    <select name="hobbies[]">
        <option>Programming</option>
        <option>Eating cats</option>
        <option>Explaining string theory to my grandmother</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And again, all is well with the world.

Now, I want to allow the user to pick more than one hobby each:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="fname[]" />
    <input type="text" name="sname[]" />
    <input type="text" name="birthdate[]" />
    <select name="hobbies[]" multiple>
        <option>Programming</option>
        <option>Eating cats</option>
        <option>Explaining string theory to my grandmother</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and this is where things start going a little pear-shaped. When I call `serialize()` now, all the hobbies are put into one array - so I'm unable to say which user has which hobbies.

I've tried using `[][]` instead of `[]` but that just puts each individual item into it's own array within the hobbies array so I still lose the user->hobby link.

The only way that I can see of doing this is writing my own `serialize()` which groups things as I need them.

Is there a better, simpler or more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

My standard approach is to append the `UserID` to the input name, with an underscore between them.

So, instead of this:

```
<input type="text" name="fname[]" />
```

it would be:

```
<input type="text" name="fname_23423" />
```

Then, server-side, you split the input names on `_`. The first element is the input name, the second is the `UserID`, and you're all set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have considered an approach similar to this. The problem is that I'm modifiying a form which is already in use which will now sometimes have multiple selects in it. So, I was hoping there was some HTML or javascript trick that I was missing that wouldn't require as much change to the existing structure.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem but the way I did it was to assign each user a specific array

for example [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7mda/)

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="user1[fname]" />
    <input type="text" name="user1[sname]" />
    <input type="text" name="user1[birthdate]" />
    <select name="user1[hobbies]" multiple>
        <option>Programming</option>
        <option>Eating cats</option>
        <option>Explaining string theory to my grandmother</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" id="submit">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the variation on the other answer that I've been considering. The problem, as with the other answer, is that it moves the problem of turning everything back into an array of arrays to the server.

Comment: This fixes the problem where all the hobbies are in one array. Each user has his own array of data. If you can't change too much in the frontend and backend, then you might have to create your own serialize function that generates a "package" that the server will understand. I guess you could still use this method, go through each different 'name' group and collect the information you need.

Comment: It definitely is a possible solution to the problem, that's why I upvoted it. I'm currently looking into creating a function to do the serialization in the way I need.